# Scrollable Absolute Position Button

Tags: react-native

How to create `Gmail` like a `floating action` button in react native

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{ zIndex: 99, position: 'absolute', top: height/1.4,  
    right: 10,  justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', 
    backgroundColor: Colors.Primary, height: height/10, width: 
    width/5.5, borderRadius: width/2.2 }} >
       <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}> Compose </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple floating button

```
<TouchableOpacity
   style={{
       borderWidth:1,
       borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
       alignItems:'center',
       justifyContent:'center',
       width:70,
       position: 'absolute',                                          
       bottom: 10,                                                    
       right: 10,
       height:70,
       backgroundColor:'#fff',
       borderRadius:100,
     }}
 >
   <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}> Compose </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

If you want an advance solution https://github.com/mastermoo/react-native-action-button